# Finding the Firebase 'path' for triggering in Zapier

Tags: firebase, zapier

I'm trying to trigger new records in a database in Zapier. Problem is, it requires the 'path':

Specify the path to the object's key which contains the child objects to be queried, such as foo/bar/here

I'm not familiar at all with the Firbase UI and am having a tough go of finding the path for the database.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking a question about configuring Zapier or reading data from Firebase? Also which Firebase product are you using as there are a number of them.

Comment: Yes, how to configure Zapier so that it triggers off of new records in Firebase. The Zapier UI asks for the 'path' in Firebase (to the database in question). Was curious how to find the path.

Comment: Which Firebase Product, Firestore? Storage? Real Time Data Base? something else?